# Connecting one network interface to the Internet disconnects the other interface

Tags: ip, internet, route

We have got an HP-UX server, but whenever I got connected to that machine using the ethernet cable I got disconnected from internet although my laptop has 2 nw interfaces. One wired one wireless. Why? How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you using to connect (`ssh`, `telnet`)? Are you disconnected immediately or after some inactivity? And what OS is your laptop running?

Comment: Ssh and windows 7. Whenever I plug the cable in, immediately I got disconnected.